# No error message displayed on MYSQL Workbench latest version

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu, syntax-error, mysql-workbench

I am running the latest version of MYSQL Workbench on a clean ubuntu 14.04 install, using the ubuntu package version.

When I run a valid query, it works fine, e.g.:

```
select * from users;
```

At the bottom of the window in what I would call the 'Status Bar' it says 'Executing Query...' for a few seconds while the query runs, and then changes to 'Query Completed' and displays the results.

So far so good.

If I then change the query to something invalid, e.g. :

```
select * from invalid_table;
```

The status bar says 'Executing Query...' and stays that way. I cannot see the error message reported anywhere.

If I run the same query in a terminal I get:

```
mysql> select * from invalid_table;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydb.invalid_table' doesn't exist
```

Surely the error message should show in workbench? 
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is displayed within the [Output History panel](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-develop-sql-editor-history.html), at the bottom. It's possible your bottom panel is deactivated, or hidden. The linked documentation includes annotated screenshots and examples.

Comment: Is there a way to customize it ? The error history is so weird :/

Comment: Seems like I have to clear the history every single time

Comment: It's not customizable, but we are thinking about reworking that in future versions of MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 2):

Did you hide the output panel?

`View`->`panels` -> `show the output area`

Or you may drag the `output panel`mini. You can move your mouse above the status bar , the mouse will turn to double arrow icon, then `drag it` and the output panel will show .